# Error while using CMake. Running "NMake-?" failed building for the Raspberry pi Pico

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi-pico, nmake

I know that there are a few articles similar to this however they all recommend using MinGW. I want to avoid MinGW as I am developing for the Raspberry pi Pico, and explicitly need NMake (As far as the raspberry pi docs will say)

This is the error I get:

```
`
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
[cmake]   Running
[cmake] 
[cmake]    'nmake' '-?'
[cmake] 
[cmake]   failed with:
[cmake] 
[cmake]    The system cannot find the file specified
[cmake] 
`
```

Is there any way to fix this without MinGW?

Comment: "Is there any way to fix this without MinGW?" - Install `nmake`, or choose any other [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) (make sure that corresponding build tool is installed).

Comment: How do I install nmake, its supposed to come with vs code and you cant install it anymore